# How can I find the model weights which tensorflow aware training quantization

Tags: tensorflow, quantization-aware-training

I am interesting in aware training quantization,When I convert my .pb model into .tflite and see the weight in netron.

Is the area circled in red in the photo on the same layer?
If yes, how can I convert the two different dimension into the same one?  (area circled in green)

model is [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1VIQCY1bzn1r0vGcSnmmcGLfduSnZQHx7?usp=sharing) :

I'm sorry that my reputation is less than 10,I can't show the picture directly.I will edit this topic when my reputation is enough.

`![PICTURE is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Guycm.jpg)`

Comment: Please refrain from posting links to images.

Comment: where is your image......

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Guycm.jpg